# Alterar endereço de WebService em tempo de execução - C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, windows-ce

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que deverá se conectar a diversos **Web services** de acordo com a localização do usuário.

**Por exemplo**:

> Se o usuário estiver na cidade "**A**" ele se conectará ao Web service: `192.168.1.1:8010` se ele for para a cidade "**B**", irá se conectar ao `192.168.1.1:8020`, na cidade "**C**" `192.168.1.1:8030`, e assim por diante.
>
> O endereço é sempre o mesmo, o que muda é a porta.

Coisa simples né?! Pois é, mas não consigo fazer isso funcionar em tempo de execução de jeito nenhum!

> Quando altero o parâmetro `URL` do Web service em tempo de execução o servidor só retorna `null`, voltando para o valor original a comunicação se restabelece. A mesma coisa se a alteração for feita antes da compilação, ou seja, compilo pra cidade "**A**", funciona na cidade "**A**", compilo pra cidade "**B**", funciona na cidade "**B**".

A aplicação está sendo desenvolvida originalmente para Windows CE utilizando o VS2008 e CF3.5, contudo mesmo na VS2013 com .Net Framework 4.0 o "problema" se repete.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Criei uma nova aplicação apenas para testar a troca do servidor, segue o código:

```
WebReference.WSR testeWS = new WebReference.WSR();

private void btn_Troca_URL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (URL_01)
    {
        testeWS.Url = "http://192.168.1.1:8010/WSR.apw";
        URL_01 = false;
    }
    else
    {
        testeWS.Url = "http://192.168.1.1:8020/WSR.apw";
        URL_01 = true;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso a URL original(compilada) é `"http://192.168.1.1:8010/WSR.apw"` e para essa URL funciona tudo normalmente, quando clico no botão e mudo para a URL `"http://192.168.1.1:8020/WSR.apw"`, só tenho null como reposta. Clicando novamente e voltando para a URL original, tudo volta a funcionar.

Se o código for compilado para a URL `"http://192.168.1.1:8020/WSR.apw"` o "problema" se inverte.

Lembrando que a propriedade "URL Behavior" está setada como Dynamic.

Comment: Coloque o trecho de código que faz a conexão com o web service atualmente para em cima dele sugerir como fazer.

Comment: Código incluído acima.

Comment: Eu sei que não é uma das melhores práticas, mas tu já pensou em referenciar todos os web services e instanciar e usar o correto apenas?

Comment: Nas properties do webservice, uma das propriedades lá deve estar como dynamic... Dá uma olhada aí! Seleciona a referência do WS e aperta F4

Comment: Desistimos de fazer esse negócio funcionar dessa forma e unificamos os webservices, passando as cidades como parâmetro. Não é melhor prática, mas pelo menos conseguimos atingir o objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Recomendo não adicionar a referencia (Web Service) em seu projeto. Assim você terá mais controle no código sobre como consumir este web service.
2. Utilize [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou uma biblioteca como [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

### Usando RestSharp

```
//MEU EndPoint
var endPointRM = "{minha url WS}"


var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest(endPointRM, Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("matricula", matricula);
var usuario = client.Execute<UsuarioRM>(request).Data;

if (usuario != null)
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Nome", usuario.Nome.Trim() }, { "Email", usuario.Email.Trim() } };
return null;
```

### Usando WebRequest

```
var response = GetResponseWS(matricula.ToString());
if (response ==  null)
    return null;
var usr = ConvertFromStream(response.GetResponseStream());

if (usr != null)
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Nome", usr.Nome.Trim() }, { "Email", usr.Email.Trim() } };
return null;
```

E os métodos auxiliares:

```
private HttpWebResponse GetResponseWS(string matricula)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetSoapEnvelope(matricula));
    //Initialization, webrequest
    HttpWebRequest WebReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPointRM);

    //Set the method/action type
    WebReq.Method = "POST";

    //We use form contentType
    WebReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";

    //The length of the buffer
    WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    //We open a stream for writing the post  data
    Stream MyPostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();

    //Now we write, and after wards, we close. Closing is always important!
    MyPostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    MyPostData.Close();

    //Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
    WebResponse resp;
    try
    {
        resp = WebReq.GetResponse();
        return (HttpWebResponse)resp;
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(wex);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        return null;
    }
}

private string GetSoapEnvelope(string matricula)
{
    return string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
<soap:Body>
<ConsultarInformacoesFuncionarioRmPorMatriculaPorColigada xmlns=""http://www.aec.com.br/"">
<matricula>{0}</matricula>
<codColigada>{1}</codColigada>
<token>{2}</token>
</ConsultarInformacoesFuncionarioRmPorMatriculaPorColigada>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>", matricula, 3, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tokenWS"]);
}

private UsuarioWS ConvertFromStream(Stream stream)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(new StreamReader(stream), XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

    return new UsuarioWS
    {
        Nome = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NOME"].ToString()
        ,
        Email = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMAIL"].ToString()
    };
}
```